# Existence of constant $C$ so that $|f'(z)|\le C\int_{\mathbb D}|f(x+iy)|dx\;dy$ for $|z| \leq 1/2$, where $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb D$

Tags: complex-analysis

> 7. Show that there is a constant $C<\infty$ so that if $f$ is analytic on $\Bbb D$, then $$\lvert f'(z)\rvert \le C \int_{\mathbb D} \lvert f(x+iy)\rvert dx\;dy$$ for all $\lvert z\rvert\le 1/2$.

[(original screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R42Ck.png)

I don't know how to do problem seven. I tried to use Cauchy's estimate. But it seems that I need to assume uniform boundedness for the family of analytic functions on the unit disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $\overline {D(a,r)}\subset \mathbb {D},$ then

$$f(a) = \frac{1}{\pi r^2} \int_{D(a,r)}f dA \implies |f(a)| \le \frac{1}{\pi r^2}\int_{\mathbb {D}}|f| dA,$$

where $A$ is area measure.